# Twilio - Save Output Of TwiML Bin To Use In IVR Flow

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Twilio noob - I'm trying to make a multilingual prompt for our IVR and I saw a suggestion to save the output of a TwiML Bin using similar code as shown below and then reference that audio file in the IVR flow, but how do I actually play/save the output of the bin?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Response>
    <Say voice="alice" language="en-US">For English, press 1.</Say>
    <Say voice="alice" language="es-MX">Para español, presione 2.</Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why would you want to save the audio output of this TwiML file when you could just use this TwiML file to speak out the prompts?

Comment: I'm designing the IVR flow using Twilio Studio and the only options available to me are to "Say A Message" which gives me a prompt to enter in the text to speak, or "Play A Message" which requires a URL to a hosted audio file to play.  Ideally I would love to reference this bin so I could just adjust the verbiage there if I need to, but since I didn't see a way of doing that the next best option would be to save off a recording of the TwiML playback and then reference that audio file in Studio.

Comment: Ah, yeah, Studio is not set up to have two languages in one Gather widget. You could record the TwiML Bin by setting up another call that dials to a number that is linked to this Bin and then uses `<Record>` to make the recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this with the help of the Functions module in Twilio.  First create a Service and create a function within the service with a similar layout as below.  The key part is to populate the action attribute with the webhook URL that you find in the Trigger widget of your Studio flow and append `?FlowEvent=return` to the end of that URL.  After deploying that function, click the "Copy URL" link in the function editor and then go into your Studio flow.  Add a TwiML Redirect widget and paste in the URL you just copied, then from that point on in the flow you can reference the digits entered by the user as `{{widgets.[TwiMLRedirectWidgetName].Digits}}`

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let twimlResponse = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  let gatherValues = twimlResponse.gather({
      input: 'dtmf',
      timeout: 15,
      numDigits: 1,
      action: "[WebhookURL]?FlowEvent=return"
  });

  gatherValues.say(
  {
    voice: 'alice',
    language: 'en-US'
  }, 'For English, press 1.');

  gatherValues.say(
  {
    voice: 'alice',
    language: 'es-MX'
  }, 'Para español, presione 2.');

  return callback(null, twimlResponse);
};
```